# Armor enchantment on a held item 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I enchant a held item with a working armor enchantment (eg. a stick with respiration)?
I can use commands to give the item the enchantment, but it currently seems to have no effect when I am holding it.
I'm using 1.14

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't very clear. What I mean was is there a way to put an enchantment designed for armour (eg. thorns or respiration) on a non-armour item (eg. a stick) and then have it work in your hand (eg. I hold a stick with respiration and get the respiration effect from it)

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that by editing the item's "`Enchantments`" NBT tag, which is not possible in a playet's inventory. You can only use `/replaceitem` to overwrite it with a new item or ask the player to drop it, then you can modify the drop.

Example for `/replaceitem`:

```
/replaceitem entity @p weapon.mainhand stick{tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"knockback",lvl:8}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the enchant command given up above my answer that command will enchant your item at any enchantment level! Also any enchantment in the game!

Comment: Remember to use the command below -------->